# Why is this answer wrong? (quadratic functions)

Tags: roots, quadratics

Question:

> Determine the quadratic function that has the given roots
>   (x-intercepts) and passes though the given point.

$x=2+\sqrt{5}, x=2 - \sqrt{5}$. The given point is $(2,10)$.

This is my answer: $y=2(x-2+√5)(x-2-√5)$

Is this correct? In the handout it says that the $a$ value should be 4, which I think is incorrect.

Comment: Where is $x$ in your answer? Also, what's the given point?

Comment: What is the "given point"?

Comment: Corrections are made.

Comment: If you plug in $x=2$, you get $y=-10$, not $y=10$.  That should tell you that $a=2$ is wrong.  You're right that $a=4$ is wrong, too, though.

Comment: 2 doesn't seem correct either, perhaps $-2$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since they're roots it means that $y=0$ when $x=2\pm \sqrt5$. Therefore, you're looking for an equation of this sort:

$$y=\alpha (x-2-\sqrt5)(x-2+\sqrt5)$$

Because when $x$ is equal to these values, the entire expression will equal $0$.

Now the next thing is the given point. That will determine the value of $\alpha$. Since $y=10$ at $x=2$:

$$10=\alpha(2-2-\sqrt5)(2-2+\sqrt5)=-5\alpha\\\therefore \alpha=-2$$

And so you have:

$$y=-2(x-2-\sqrt5)(x-2+\sqrt5)$$

Which is a quadratic function (if you were to FOIL it out).